# Do I need to have an HttpRequest object if I'm using render_to_response?

Tags: python, django, http, authentication

Django is telling me that my login view isn't returning an HttpResponse object:

```
The view accounts.views.login didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

However, I'm using `render_to_response()` everywhere and there is no way the view could finish resolving without getting a response. Here's the code:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    auth_login(request, user)
                    render_to_response('list.html')
                else:
                    error = "It seems your account has been disabled."
                    render_to_response('list.html', {'error': error})
            else:
                error = "Bad login information. Give it another go."
                render_to_response('list.html', {'error': error})
        else:
            error = "Bad login information. Give it another go."
            render_to_response('list.html', {'error': error})
    else:
        error = "Whoa, something weird happened. You sure you're using the form on our site?"
        render_to_response('list.html', {'error': error})
```

I'm sure the code could be more efficient (less renders), but this should work, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the **return**

```
return render_to_response('list.html', {'error': error})
```

Comment: *sigh*, I need to get more sleep. Thank you very much and I apologize for wasting your time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the render_to_response's response. I suggest you some code improvements also:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    auth_login(request, user)
                    return render_to_response('list.html')
                else:
                    error = "It seems your account has been disabled."
            else:
                error = "Bad login information. Give it another go."
        else:
            error = "Bad login information. Give it another go."
    else:
        error = "Whoa, something weird happened. You sure you're using the form on our site?"
    return render_to_response('list.html', {'error': error})
```